# Firestore Security Rule - Validate incoming data length is greater than 2 but field is not required

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know how to check if a field of an incoming data set is a string or not, but how do I do a conditional check if the field exists, then check if its a string:

For example, "last name" is not a required field, but if it's supplied, then check if its length is greater than 2. I get an error if I just check the length rule generally -> is there a way to check the length only if last_name exists?

Firestore Rule: 
request.resource.data.last_name.length() > 0

Answer (score 4):

Function for validating that field would be like this:

```
function isLastNameValid() {
  return request.resource.data.last_name == null || request.resource.data.last_name.size() > 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking if a value is a string is effectively the same as checking for existence.  So if you do this:

```
request.resource.data.last_name is string
```

It will also return false if it doesn't exist.

But if you don't care what the type is, and you just want to check if it exists at all (as a string, number, whatever):

```
"last_name" in request.resource.data
```

[request.resource.data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data) is a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map), so check it's documentation at those links.